# How to re-read some byte from InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm using a BufferedInputStream to read an InputStream in chunks and sending that chunk through a request to an API.

The problem is the API return a response with the Range header to indicate the received bytes. When that Range is less than the chunk size, I need to go back and send the missing bytes... how can I do that with InputStream?

As example: I send 100 bytes but the API received only 90 bytes, so previously I maked the BufferedInputStream on that bytes, if I reset, I go back 100 bytes and I can re-read that 100 bytes but I only need the last 10 bytes of that portion....

```
while( totalBytesRead < totalSize ) {
    byte[] content = new byte[chunkSize];
    bufferedInputStream.mark(chunkSize);
    int bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(content, 0, chunkSize);
    //call API and verify how much receive
    if( !receiveLess ) {
         bufferedInputStream.reset();
         // how to re-read the bytes that API no received??
    }
}
```

Comment: Without specific code, it is very difficult to help you. However, just stash the bit you read in until you get the response and you should be fine.

Comment: Just read in the bytes you need to send and send those bytes. If it fails, just resend the relevant bytes from the current chunk of bytes in memory. Upon success, read the next chunk of bytes. Rinse and repeat until you're done.

Comment: You're really going to have to store the whole contents of the stream to do this.